# Как использовать в качестве результата для агрегации группировки лист?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Что-то похожее на, то что мне нужно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43664415/7542937). Только мне хотелось бы это в виде LINQ и с возможностью агрегации не в строку, а в список.

Вот посмотрите, у меня есть такая таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу выбрать `Title`, `PackageId`, `Category`, `Advertiser`, `TemplateType`, сгруппировать по `Title`, `Category` и `TemplateType`. А вот что касается `Advertiser` и `PackageId`, то тут не все так просто. Мне нужна агрегация, но не простая. Я не хочу искать максимум или сумму или среднее. Мне нужно поместить их в лист. Ну или хотя бы объединить в строку через запятую. В приведенной выше ссылке так и делается, но для SQL Server и там конкатенация в строку. А мне было бы идеально в лист.

Не нашел того, как это сделать. Может кто-то знает какой-то хитрый трюк?

#### Update

Поясню подробнее. Вот у меня есть такой запрос и результат работы: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А я хотел бы, чтоб две строки схлопнулись в одну, а колонка `PackageId` содержала бы два значения: `com.track.event.new` и `com.track.event`. И все это на LINQ. Было бы просто идеально!

#### Update 2

Как просили ниже в комментариях, я добавляю исходные данные.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получены данные таким запросом

```
select  M."Title", P."PackageId", "Advertiser",  "Category", P."TemplateType" from "Pushes" P
inner join "ManuallySendings" M on P."ManuallySendingId" = M."ManuallySendingId"
where "PushType" = 'manually'
```

Как видите, есть еще таблица `ManuallySendings` из которой мне нужен только `Title`.

Пытаясь реализовать данную задачу я написал вот такой код:

```
 var pushes = _pushRepository.Pushes.Include(x => x.ManuallySending)
                .Where(x => x.PushType == "manually");

            var res = from push in pushes
                group push by new
                {
                    push.Category,
                    push.TemplateType,
                    push.ManuallySending,
                }
                into pg
                select new PushStatisticManuallySendingIndexViewModel
                {
                    Title = pg.Key.ManuallySending.Title,
                    AppIds = pg.Select(x => x.PackageId).Distinct(),
                    CategoryName = pg.Key.Category,
                    Id = pg.FirstOrDefault().ManuallySending.ManuallySendingId,
                    TemplateType = pg.Key.TemplateType
                };
```

#### Update 3

Я нашел как это сделать в базе данных (я использую Postgres)

```
select M."Title", array_agg(P."PackageId"), "Advertiser",  "Category", P."TemplateType"
from "Pushes" P
inner join "ManuallySendings" M on M."ManuallySendingId" = P."ManuallySendingId"
group by M."Title", "Advertiser", "Category", P."TemplateType";
```

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Осталась только понять, как сделать то же самое и на LINQ!

Comment: А дайте пожалуйста входные данные и что в итоге хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ минуту, я обновлю и добавлю пример входных данных. Что касается выходных данных, то мне нужно то, что есть после Update, только это должна быть одна строка, а не две. Должна произойти "конкатенация" поля `PackageId`, как я описал в вопросе.

Comment: Вы не предоставили мне данных, с которыми я могу работать, лишь  картинка c явно не тем, что вы получаете с базы. Ну чтож, вот вам слепок из того, что имеем: `var result = Items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Title, x.Category, x.TemplateType }).Select(x => new { x.Key.Title, x.Key.Category, x.Key.TemplateType, Id = x.Select(k => k.PackageId) });`  в результате будет анонимный тип (можно заменить на класс), который будет содержать `Title`, `Category`, `TemplateType` и `Id` - коллекцию всех `TemplateType` данной группировки.